# I can't build AwesomiumSharp version from github

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

Anyone using https://github.com/khrona/AwesomiumSharp? I am trying to build the AwesomiumSharp but get the following errors:

`Error   2   The command "XCOPY ..........\build\bin\release\icudt42.dll "C:\Users\demo\Desktop\July2012\khrona-AwesomiumSharp-423f277\AwesomiumSharp\bin\x86\Debug\" /i /y
XCOPY ..........\build\bin\release\avcodec-52.dll "C:\Users\demo\Desktop\July2012\khrona-AwesomiumSharp-423f277\AwesomiumSharp\bin\x86\Debug\" /i /y
XCOPY ..........\build\bin\release\avformat-52.dll "C:\Users\demo\Desktop\July2012\khrona-AwesomiumSharp-423f277\AwesomiumSharp\bin\x86\Debug\" /i /y
XCOPY ..........\build\bin\release\avutil-50.dll "C:\Users\demo\Desktop\July2012\khrona-AwesomiumSharp-423f277\AwesomiumSharp\bin\x86\Debug\" /i /y
XCOPY ..........\build\bin\release\Awesomium.dll "C:\Users\demo\Desktop\July2012\khrona-AwesomiumSharp-423f277\AwesomiumSharp\bin\x86\Debug\" /i /y
XCOPY ..........\build\bin\release\AwesomiumProcess.exe "C:\Users\demo\Desktop\July2012\khrona-AwesomiumSharp-423f277\AwesomiumSharp\bin\x86\Debug\" /i /y
XCOPY ..........\build\bin\Release\locales\en-US.dll "C:\Users\demo\Desktop\July2012\khrona-AwesomiumSharp-423f277\AwesomiumSharp\bin\x86\Debug\locales\" /i /y`

XCOPY ..........\build\bin\debug\Awesomium_d.dll "C:\Users\demo\Desktop\July2012\khrona-AwesomiumSharp-423f277\AwesomiumSharp\bin\x86\Debug\" /i /y
XCOPY ..........\build\bin\debug\AwesomiumProcess_d.exe "C:\Users\demo\Desktop\July2012\khrona-AwesomiumSharp-423f277\AwesomiumSharp\bin\x86\Debug\" /i /y
" exited with code 4.   AwesomiumSharp

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XCOPY commands are in the startup projects properties on the build events tab, you need to  amend to your disk or remove them (depending on what they are doing, I am unsure.)

Same for the Mono project I am guessing.....

[image]

-------------------- EDIT ----------------------

I managed to get it compiling the code, I followed the readme and installed the SDK on my D:\

I then copied the source in the same folder as the readme into the following folder:

```
D:\Awesomium\1.6.6\wrappers\Awesomium.NET\AwesomiumSharp
```

I then went into the properties and added in front of the xcopy source path an extra ..\ so that it went down to the correct folder and now it compiles.

[image]

It should be then copied from here:

[image]

Good luck!

Comment: Yeah not sure what to do with them.

Comment: Try mapping them all to a common folder (as a test)

Comment: I think I copied the source in the wrong folder which was why I had to add an extra ..\ in the xcopy command, so if you copy the AwesomiumSharp folder containing all the projects into the wrappers folder it should compile without any changes, when you have got the SDK to install correctly that is :)